# libgdx table padding for multiple sizes

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have a problem and maybe someone of you could help me, I'am trying to make Login panel and I have created stage, table and everything goes to table so I'am tring to make that title would padBottom for multiple sizes but I'am unlucky in this.

My code: windowTitle is Label;

```
table.add(windowTitle).colspan(2).padBottom(0.15f * table.getHeight()).align(Align.topLeft);
    table.getCell(windowTitle).width(table.getWidth() - (0.1f * table.getWidth()));
    table.getCell(windowTitle).padLeft(0.1f * table.getWidth());
```

And this is the output I get:

[1280x720]

[SCREENSHOT](http://server.edgu.lt/ignas/2015-08-18_05-42-25.png)

Fullscreen ~1920x1080

[SCREENSHOT](http://server.edgu.lt/ignas/2015-08-18_05-42-36.png)

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but you answered your question... You should try messing around with `0.15f * table.getHeight()`
change .15f to some lower or higher value and you will soon notice the difference.
In addition I would recommend adding an empty cell/line it seems like the perfect size for your layout:

```
table.row();
table.add();
table.row();
```

I hope I understood your question...